# WSO2-APIM (v1.9.1) Running from Docker, cant create a new API using swagger URL

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I created a Docker image based on centos:6.6, oracle java 7.79 and wso2-apim v1.9.1. It also expose the ports 9763 9443 8280 8243.

I also tried with a docker images in [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/isim/wso2apim/) with the same result error.

I can start a new container whithout problems but I can not create a new API using swagger URL when login as 'admin' in the https://:9443/publisher.
The swagger URL that I use is http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json

I also tried using a simple hello world REST with swagger2 that exist in my local machine (http ://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs) and I get the same error.

I get a connection refused error?

```
[2015-11-11 11:55:49,571] ERROR - XMLHttpRequestHostObject Connection refused
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
...
Org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_design.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-design/ajax/add.jag)
...
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
...
[2015-11-11 11:55:49,579] ERROR - WebAppManager org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException:
Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (http#220) org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException:
org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException:
Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (http#220)
```

Using the wso2-apim binary does not gives this error. So it has to be something with docker setting or bug in distribution?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a networking issue. Above Swagger endpoints might not be visible to the container. Try to log into the container using the below command and verify the visibility of the endpoints using curl:

```
docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash
curl http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json
```

If the endpoints are not visible, please refer below StackOverflow question to resolve the networking issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions//my-docker-container-has-no-internet

Regarding the Swagger endpoints hosted in your local machine, depending on how you run Docker they might not be accessible to the container using localhost. You might need to use the IP address of your local machine.

Comment: I'm with the same issue. How did you solve?